# Returning start point of a program with While Loop

Tags: c#

First of all, I am sorry for the easy question but I could not handle it on my own because I just started coding.
I coded this little game. I need to restart it if user hits the `y` key.

My problem is that I figured it out how to restore life, meter and points but I cant fix the random number (which we need to find to win): it's not changing.

Hope my description will be clear enough:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int QuestionNumber = (new Random()).Next(1, 10);
    int life = 5;
    int meter = 0;
    int number;
    int points = 100;
    char selection = 'y';

    while (selection == 'y')
    {
        life = 5;
        meter = 0;
        points = 100;

        while (life > 0)
        {
            meter++;
            Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
            number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (number == QuestionNumber)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Congrats! You found the number at {meter}th and got {points} points!");
                break;
            }
            life--;
            points = points - 20;

            if (life == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Game over!");
            }
            else
            {
                if (number > QuestionNumber)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Down");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Up");
                }
            }
        }
        Console.Write("Do you want to countinue?(y/n)");
        selection = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Probably you want to move the line `int QuestionNumber = (new Random()).Next(1, 10);` inside outer `while`

Comment: Because you assign it on the first line. If you want to generate a new number in the loop then do that **in the loop**. Also do not create a new `Random` instance every time you need a new number, create the instance once and then refer to that instance in the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

```
while (selection == 'y')
{
  life = 5;
  meter = 0;
```

To this, instead:

```
while (selection == 'y')
{
  QuestionNumber = (new Random()).Next(1, 10);
  life = 5;
  meter = 0;
```

That way, `QuestionNumber` gets reset just like it was instantiated up top to start with.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the QuestionNumber is only assigned a value once in your program. In order to change the QuestionNumber, you need to assign it a new random value inside your while loop.